# How do you compare the value of an array to a variable in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm practicing bash and honestly, it is pretty fun. However, I'm trying to write a program that compares an array's value to a variable and if they are the same then it should print the array's value with an asterisk to the left of it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

color[0]=red
color[1]=blue
color[2]=black
color[3]=brown
color[4]=yellow
favorite="black"

for i in {0..4};do echo ${color[$i]};
if {"$favorite"=$color[i]}; then
    echo"* $color[i]"
done
```

output should be `*black`

Comment: What is the code outputting now?

Comment: Your script is full of incorrect syntaxes.

Answer (score 4):

There's few incorrect statements in your code that prevent it from doing what you ask it to. The comparison in `bash` is done withing square brackets, leaving space around them. You correctly use the `=` for string comparison, but should enclose in `"` the string variable. Also, while you correctly address the element array in the `echo` statement, you don't do so inside the comparison, where it should read `${color[$i]}` as well. Same error in the asterisk print. So, here a reworked code with the fixes, but read more below.

```
#!/bin/bash

color[0]=red
color[1]=blue
color[2]=black
color[3]=brown
color[4]=yellow
favorite=black
for i in {0..4};do
   echo ${color[$i]};
   if [ "$favorite" = "${color[$i]}" ]; then
      echo "* ${color[$i]}"
   fi
done
```

While that code works now, few things that probably I like and would suggest (open to more expert input of course by the SO community): always enclose strings in `"`, as it makes evident it is a string variable; when looping an array, no need to use index variables; enclose variables always within `${}`.
So my version of the same code would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
color=("red" "blue" "black" "brown" "yellow")
favorite="black"
for item in ${color[@]}; do
   echo ${item}
   if [ "${item}" = "${favorite}" ]; then
     echo "* $item"
   fi
done
```

And a pointer to the great Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/